# при добавлений Retrofit в NestedScrollView в виде списка RecycleView выходит ошибка

Tags: java, android

список очень долго прогружается и зависает а после вылетает

без NestedScrollView и CollapsingToolbarLayout работает хорошо что делать

вот код как работает приложение много раз расходует память(не знаю как правильно написать)

[image: код]

ошибка во вкладке ran
[image: ошибка во вкладке ran]
код ошибки
[image: код ошибки]

код самого фрагмента

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pizza"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

код класса форагмент

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new ImageAdapter(postsList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    fetchPosts();


    return view;
}

private void fetchPosts() {

    postviewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(PostviewModel.class);
    postviewModel.getPosts();

    postviewModel.mutableLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Photos_POJO>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Photos_POJO> photos_pojos) {
            adapter.getPostsList(photos_pojos);
        }
    });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

код ViewModel

```
public MutableLiveData<List<Photos_POJO>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void getPosts(){

    RetrofitClient.getINSTANCE().getPhoto().enqueue(new Callback<List<Photos_POJO>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Photos_POJO>> call, Response<List<Photos_POJO>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                mutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Photos_POJO>> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
}
```

код POJO

```
public Photos_POJO(String title, String body) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
```

код адаптера

```
public void getPostsList(List<Photos_POJO> photos_pojos) {
    this.postsList = photos_pojos;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvTitle.setText(postsList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvBody.setText(postsList.get(position).getBody());

    Picasso.get().load(postsList.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postsList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvBody;
    ImageView imageView;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvBody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Comment: это не код ошибки, когда приложение будет падать то в вкладке logcat будет много красного текста, его нужно скопировать в вопрос, разметку с виджетом нужно прикреплять в виде текста, изображения которые касаются кода не должны присутствовать в текста вопроса

Comment: получается при сборке нет ошибок , есть только когда начинают подгружаться данные. начинаешь жутко лагать а после вылетает

Comment: А зачем там `NestedScrollView`? Судя по всему ресайклер внутри него разворачивается в полный размер - то есть создаёт вью для каждого элемента списка и это съедает всю память.

Comment: @woesss да я вот без него делаю все работает и не вылетает только теперь при прокрутке AppBarLayout не прилипает к верху экрана

Comment: Ну вот по этой проблеме вам и нужно задать вопрос - показать разметку фрагмента полностью и объяснить что с ней не так. И если вдруг вылеты не прекратятся после исправления разметки - тогда обновите этот вопрос подробностями.

Comment: @woesss сасибо за совет сейчас попробую найти инфу как использовать без NestedScrollView и попробую сделать

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо разобраться с основной фишкой `recycleview`

Он НЕ отображает список целиком. Он показывает лишь те item'ы, что сейчас видит пользователь (ну и + парочка сверху и снизу). Когда вы скролите ресайкл вниз/вверх - происходит новых элементов, а старые стираются. Это надо для того, чтобы UI приложения был более быстрый.

Теперь, что происходит, когда `recycleview` помещают в `nestedscrollview`?

Происходит, грубо говоря, "выключение" основной фишки `recycleview`, которая описана выше. Т.е. все данные СРАЗУ же помещаются в ресайкл, что затратно для приложения. Вы сами это заметили:
*"без NestedScrollView работает хорошо"*

Что еще может быть не так?

**№1 метод fetchPosts**
Вы "кормите" адаптер данные через слушателя LiveData, а вот "обновление" ресайкла где-то в стороне. Для полноты картины надо посмотреть "в каком формате вам приходят данные по сети? это сразу целый массив, или по 1 объекту, которые заполняют массив?"

**№2 onCreateView**
вы все делаете в момент onCreateView. возможно, стоит это делать в методе onViewCreated. почитайте, чем эти жизненные этапы фрагмента отличаются друг от друга.

**№3 Потоки**
Не ясно, в каком потоке вы все это выполняете. Лог вашей ошибки говорит о том, что приложению недостаточно памяти. Причиной этому может быть так же быть то, что все это приосходит в mainThread. Попробуйте получить данные для LiveData в другом потоке, а потом через слушателя отобразить их в Ресайкле.
LiveData полностью раскрывает свой функционал именно в потоках.
Так же есть вопрос о том, КАК вы меняете данные LiveData: просто присваиваете или метод postValue() ?

В любом случае, у вас проблемы именно с оптимизацией кода.

Comment: добрый день, спасибо за ответ .

 я дополнил текст вопроса и вызываю не в основном потоке . 

обновление adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); проходит сразу чуть ниже и в самом адаптере.

можете прокомментировать тот код что я добавил все ли коректно .

Заранее спасибо

Comment: @александркушнарев а если вы удалите   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); в методе fetchPosts , что будет? по идеи, все должно отображаться корректно.

Comment: @александркушнарев код, вроде как, адекватный и нормальный. ничего резкого в глаза не бросается. да и без NestetedScroll все работает. проблема в моменте, когда "надо отобразить ВСЕ данные сразу". за отображение отвечает Picasso, и я думаю внутри библиотеки 99% это сделанно тоже асинхронно.

Comment: спасибо за советы, теперь все отлично работает с RecycleView . вот только у меня не срабатывал CollapsingToolbarLayout. нужно было убрать Toolbar после ImageView и все заработало как я планировал.